# NSUserDefaults synchronize crash

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have encountered a SIGSEGV crash in my ios app right after calling:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This is the part of the crash stack trace right after the synchronize command:

```
CoreFoundation 0x31920232 CFCopyTypeIDDescription + 29
CoreFoundation 0x3191cd41 <redacted> + 204
CoreFoundation 0x31910815 <redacted> + 16
CoreFoundation 0x3188e1ac <redacted> + 140
CoreFoundation 0x3189d1ff CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 158
CoreFoundation 0x3191c483 <redacted> + 282
CoreFoundation 0x318b237f CFPropertyListWriteToStream + 138
CoreFoundation 0x318b115d <redacted> + 296
CoreFoundation 0x318b1031 <redacted> + 132
CoreFoundation 0x318b03c1 <redacted> + 492
CoreFoundation 0x318b01d1 <redacted> + 20
CoreFoundation 0x318bb3ff <redacted> + 110
CoreFoundation 0x318bb8fb <redacted> + 74
CoreFoundation 0x3193cb3b <redacted> + 30
CoreFoundation 0x3193d509 <redacted> + 32
libdispatch.dylib 0x39bd54b7 <redacted> + 22
libdispatch.dylib 0x39bd99f7 <redacted> + 30
CoreFoundation 0x318c7045 CFPreferencesAppSynchronize + 312
```

This is a rare crash so I can't reproduce it, and my question is:

What can cause such a crash?

Comment: What do U save in UserDefaults?

Comment: Numbers (int/float), strings and dates. Nothing too fancy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do to try and avoid this kind of situation, and to have better control of the defaults, is to funnel everything through my appDelegate (a singleton class works too). The idea is that when you want to save something, you send it to the designated object, in my case:

```
[appDelegate defaultsSetObject:(id)obj forKey:(NSSString *)key];
```

In that method I `copy` the obj and key (in case they are mutable objects). If I get into trouble like you are now, I can invoke synchronize on every call (to force an immediate failure), or at least log everything.

If your problem is hard to reproduce, spending the time to re-organize your defaults code might be worth it. On the other hand, you could create a macro, replace all your defaults code with the macro, and by redefining the macro get similar behavior to what I did. [The macro would be something like:

```
SAVE_OBJECT_FOR_KEY(obj, key);
```

In the simplest command case, just save the object. When debugging, do the copy as I suggest above, save, then synchronize.

Comment: Thanks, this is some very good advice. Hopefully it will help in my case, though I can't really test it as I can't reproduce the crash myself.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some object returned from user defaults earlier has been over-released. When the dictionary inside NSUserDefaults containing the object is serialized to a plist, the crash occurs when it tries to serialize the now-dead object